# Rspec running test not showing on shell/bash and instead creating a weird lor file

Tags: ruby, rspec, oh-my-zsh

I have a car_project folder.

Inside there are 2 more folders:

1. lib folder with a car.rb file inside
2. spec folder with the car_spec.rb
3. spec_helper.rb files

Inside the car_project folder there is also an init.rb

When I run in the console the following command:

```
rspec spec/car_spec.rb
```

I get nothing on the return:

```
➜  car_project git:(master) x
```

However it creates a weird file called `lor`, with the results of the test inside

If I run the same command with `--format` documentation, then I am able to see the results of the test in the terminal.

I am using [oh-my-zshrc](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) in the terminal.

I´ve never seen this lor file in my life when running rspec test from the command line/shell/bash...any ideas?

Comment: How do your classes And tests look? How does your `spec_helper` look like? Do you have a `.rspec` file somewhere, how does it look like? What gems are you using? Can you provide a minimal example that allows reproducing this behavior?

Comment: Adding the output from`➜ find .` executed within your project's folder will help clarify the project's structure.